# filter by drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, filter

I have 2 column page the first column :
I want to create 2 drop down menus. The first contains the categories and the second has the posts that are related to the category.

With a meaning that when someone chooses the category (laptops) in the second menu only the laptops would appear. And when choosing both options and clicking submit the posts on the the other column would filter to only the product that he selected.

can you please help me with either one of them and your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what have you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: i didn't find any code yet that makes me control what appears on the second menu and the filter

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example (Nested Combos):

http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/

Comment: i didn't understand how the plugin works I am not that good in php may you explain it please ?

Comment: you have to download the file jquery.jCombo.js
and put in a folder of your project.

then you have to put the following code between your <head> and </head> tags: <script type="text/javascript" src="path/of/your/file/jquery.jCombo.min.js"></script> and now you can use the code like example